# What happened at Bloody Corner?

Tags: united-kingdom, early-medieval

Up until today, I was under the impression that there was a battle between the Danes and the locals on Bloody Corner in Northam, Devon UK.

This was possibly the death site of Hubba the Dane.
It was told that Bone Hill in Northam is the mass burial site of the invading army.

However, a new bout of research has uncovered the possibility that the battle of bloody corner was actually between King Harold's sons Edmund and Godwine with an Irish army and William the Conqueror's forces.

Is this accurate?
If so, would bone hill be the burial site of the invading Irish army?

[A link to the article](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/home-news/battle-of-hastings-sequel-tracked-down-to-north-devon-a6891756.html)

Comment: From reading the article it seems too early to tell one way or the other. If the site gets protected status and there is an archaeological excavation which turns up real evidence, then we'll be in a position to know more.